# SSRS Date parameter - foreign language issue

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssas

I have a client in Germany using an SSRS report and the date parameter is showing "OKT" instead we need it to be "OCT" for october

Is there a setting to make sure `GETDATE()` is already converted or will a convert function work?

here is my error:

> library!ReportServer_0-45!1554!10/15/2018-10:23:17:: i INFO:
>   RenderForNewSession('/Finance/MC Dashboard')
>   processing!ReportServer_0-45!10bc!10/15/2018-10:23:17:: e ERROR:
>   Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'JournalEntries'. --->
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdErrorResponseException:
>   Query (5, 39) Cannot convert value 'Okt 14, 2018' of type Text to type
>   Date.    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.IExecuteProvider.ExecuteTabular(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, ICommandContentProvider contentProvider,
>   AdomdPropertyCollection commandProperties, IDataParameterCollection
>   parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Since the GetDate is coming through in German from the server, then the SQL CONVERT function should also use German to convert it to a date.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 106)
```

If you do get an error, you might need to set the language first (SET Language German;) - though that would be wonky that one SQL function would work in German but the other doesn't.

Comment: I'm not using SQL.......or a stored proc........I am using SSRS Parameters. here is the expression:  =format(iif(Hour(now) >= 21, today, dateadd(dateinterval.Day, -1, today)), "MMM dd, yyyy")

Comment: Ahh - you had mentioned GETDATE so I **ass**u**me**d that you were getting the date from SQL Server. Can't you pass the date as a date (10/14/2018) instead of converting it to a string with the format? What's the Language of the report set to? Can you change it to EN so the format uses English?

Comment: I'm sorry.... you are correct. it should be "now()"   or "today()"    ........ the language is set to EN. i was able to recreate the error by changing the language via internet browser settings. the format needs to be specific to match the date format within the SSAS cube.

Comment: The error was because it was trying to convert OKT 14 to a date - `Cannot convert value 'Okt 14, 2018' of type Text to type Date`. Can you pass the date as 2018-10-14? As a string if necessary? It should be able to convert that to a date if necessary. I'm not sure what else to try. :\ You can format the date later if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

just capture the data first in a text box and check its format. Depending on how it looks you can worse case convert this receive input param to internal varchar and then just get the date part out. i.e.

```
declare @internal_param as varchar(15);
set @internal_param = @Input_dateParam --your variable name here
--select logic here
```

Comment: thank you. I am hoping to do all of my conversions or work either within SSRS design or change some setting on his end so that he passes English to me.  I'm still researching the easiest solution :'(

Comment: personal suggestion; dont do processing on the report server. Leave SQL server to do heavy lifting of the data calculations , and manipulation. But its just my 2 cents. If doing on report side fixes your issue by all means.

Comment: I appreciate it. But I am in a time pinch and do not want to rewrite everything. not only that, I am using SSAS